# php uploading file?

Tags: php, file-upload

I just want to know that if I am using `move_uploaded_file` function and use two argument first  as the name of file and second as the destination.

Normally I have uploaded many files with class uploader but now I want to give the destination as `http://www.example.com/testing/`

Although I have given 777 permission to this folder but when I try to execute the upload code error came

> Destination directory can't be created. Can't carry on a process.

How can I upload the file local to server using php code?

Comment: Can you show us the line of code you're using? The message indicates that it can't find the testing folder.

Comment: Are you specifying the folder relatively? You either have your path wrong or the folder doesn't exist it sounds like.

Comment: You really need to show some code.

Comment: -1 until there is some code to work with. This user has a history of ignoring requests for clarification

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing `http://www.mydomain.com/testing/` as the target, this is wrong.

You can't just upload files to servers via HTTP, you only can do that to local folders, can you paste the exact code so we can know better what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

[move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) is a server-side function, so all the paths should be specified server side.
If your upload.php (i'm assuming the filename) is in the main directory of the website www.mydomain.com/ which is probably /home/youruser/public_html/ then you can specify the destination as simply "testing/"
If your upload file is in some nested directory, then it may work better to specify the full destination path:
/home/youruser/public_html/testing

good luck